# The best way to implement the function

Tags: c, function

Having the signature of the function :

```
int my_print(const char *format, ...);
```

I want to implement it by calling `printf` with arguments passed to `my_print` and `fflush(stdout);`

What do you think the best way to implement it?

Comment: I think using a macro might be easier. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [vprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/vprintf/). It accepts a `va_list`, which is what you get in `my_print`:

```
int my_print(char * format, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  int ret = vprintf (format, args);
  va_end (args);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: It's considered a good idea to make `v*` versions of your functions as well, so if someone wants to wrap your function they can. So `int my_vprint(char *format, va_list args) { int ret = vprintf(format, args); fflush(stdout); return ret; } int my_print(char *format, ...) { va_list args; va_start(args, format); int ret = my_vprint(format, args); va_end(args); return ret; }`